# ethminer - No OpenCL platforms found for AMD Radeon HD 3870 x2

Tags: drivers, server, amd-graphics, radeon, ethereum

I am trying to mine ethereum with an ancient laptop just for fun, but I can't get it running. I get this error:

```bsh
ethminer 0.19.0-alpha.0
Build: linux/release/gnu

No OpenCL platforms found
Error: No usable mining devices found
```

Here's the setup:

**GPU:** AMD Radeon HD 3870 x2
**OS:** ubuntu server 20.04
**Miner:** ethminer 0.19.0-alpha-0

Running this command...

```bsh
sudo lshw -c video | grep driver
```

gives this:

```bsh
configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
```

What might be the problem? Is the 20.04 kernel incompatible with the drivers? Is everything too old?

Comment: You didn't provide specifics as to which kernel stack you're using with your 20.04.  Ubuntu LTS releases offer two kernel stack choices (selected at install time, or by ISO used to install; not including the OEM kernel stacks).  Your paste excluded that detail b/c of edits.  Are you using the *older* (GA) or *newer* (HWE) kernel stack choice?   Did you try the other choice?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I wasn't even aware this was a thing. I am not that versed in Linux. I will try to find the info and reply.

Comment: `uname -r` will tell you the running kernel; the GA stack will be 5.4 for the life of the product, HWE causes it to follow the non-LTS; ie. 20.04.2 was 5.8 (20.10); 20.04.3 was 5.11 (21.04), 20.04.4 is 5.13 etc.. before settling on the GA stack from the next LTS   https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack   (OEM allow further kernels but installation decide that itself; you don't choose that).

Comment: `uname -r` displayed this `5.4.0-94-generic`. I don't know how to use this information to make the GPUs work.

Comment: You're using the GA kernel stack; ie. the most *stable* but also the oldest.. Your video '*drivers*' (drivers are actually kernel modules) are thus the older choice available for 20.04.  Prior link provided details on the kernel stack choices; including installing the other stack, on most machines you can have both installed without issue, but also told you how to remove other stack too if desired (ie. *you can try, then remove unwanted option if deemed necessary*).